# accept only local branch changes during git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm using fast forward merge strategy. I'm trying to rebase while on my local branch and I want no changes from master after the rebase as I want the result to look exactly like what I have in my local branch.
I tried `git rebase -Xtheirs` but it still takes some changes from master which breaks the code and is very annoying. I tried `git checkout --theirs` but git says that it is not permissible to call it while switching branches.
How can I rebase and make sure that all master files are overridden with my local branch changes?

Comment: You have not explained what you are rebasing and why. I can't even tell which way you are going. Are you trying to rebase `branch` on top of `master` so as to pick up any changes in `master` while you were working on `branch`? Or are you trying to merge `branch` into `master` so that `master` incorporates what you did in `branch`? Or what?

Comment: hmm.. I guess it comes from my lack of deeper understanding of git probably. I would like to move the branch on top of master but I do not want to pick any changes from master. then I want to push the local branch to create a pull request.

Comment: If you do not want to pick up any changes from master, then what does “move the branch on top of master” even mean? Rebasing is _about_ picking up changes, that is _why_ you rebase before pushing for PR.

Comment: anyway, as I said, I had to rebase because otherwise, I wouldn't be able to merge the branch in gitlab. So during rebase I replaced all wrongly merged files with the files from my branch, then pushed. And then I could merge the branch in gitlab gui. I just wanted to avoid the tedious step of fixing the wrongly merged files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a soft reset

```
git checkout my-branch
git reset --soft master
```

All differences between my-branch and master will be in index ready to be committed, your worktree won't be touched

Comment: not sure how this is going to help.. I would still have to rebase afterwards.

Comment: Ah.... what? After you commit you will have a single revision _after_ master.